# Trouble with tap detection on CCLayer subclass

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, subclass, cclayer

I have a `CCLayer` subclass `MyLayer` in which I handle touch events:

```
(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *) touch withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
```

I set the content size of `MyLayer` instances like this:

```
`myLayer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(30.0, 30.0);`
```

I then add `MyLayer` instances as children of `ParentLayer`. For some reason I can tap **anywhere** on the screen and a `MyLayer` instance will detect the tap. I want to only detect taps on the visible portion/content size. **How can I do this?**

Are the `MyLayer` instances somehow inheriting a "tappable area" from somewhere else? I've verified that the `contentSize` of the instance just tapped is `(30, 30)` as expected. Perhaps the contentSize isn't the way to specify the tappable area of `CCLayer` subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the touch is enabled on a particular CCLayer, it receives all of the touch events in the window. That being said, if there are multiple layers, all layers will receive the same touches.

To alleviate this, obtain the location from the UITouch, convert it to Cocos2d coordinates, then check to see if it is within the bounds of the Layer you are concerned with.

Here's some code to work with:

```
CCLayer * ccl = [[CCLayer alloc] init];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(ccl.position.x - ccl.contentSize.width/2, ccl.position.y - ccl.contentSize.height/2, ccl.contentSize.width, ccl.contentSize.height), location)) {
   //continue from there...
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. I'm surprised a `CCLayer` would receive touches outside of it's contentSize.

Comment: It is a bit strange, I agree. However, CCLayers can be quite complex to determine the location of when they are nested in each other. This is probably to keep the main thread available to graphics processing.